# Multiple instances of vue-chartjs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js, vue-chartjs

I'm trying to implement multiple Doughnut type graphs into a single component.
Library: https://vue-chartjs.org/guide/#creating-your-first-chart

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
        <strong>Všetky</strong>
        <Doughnut chart-id="workNonWorkData" :dataset-id-key="'key1'" :chart-data="workNonWorkData" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
        <strong>Schválené</strong>
        <Doughnut chart-id="workNonWorkAprData" :dataset-id-key="'key2'" :chart-data="workNonWorkAprData" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Both doughnuts work on their own when the other one is commented out. But when I want to have both, only latter one displays. I checked canvas ids and they are different. So I'm thinking vue takes these two as the same instance?

Comment: Do you have a [repro]? Kinda surprising that this happens. Do you see any error or something weird in the console/vue devtools?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/apertureless/vue-chartjs/tree/main/legacy/sandboxes/doughnut?file=/src/App.vue place a div under <template> and then make a copy of the doughnutchart. same result.

Answer (score 2):

I was using the `4.0.4` version, downgraded it to the `4.0.3` version and it works.

Hope it helps.

Comment: i already moved to pure chart.js without the vue-chartjs wrapper. but it's a good tip, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script>
import { Doughnut } from "vue-chartjs";
import Chart from "chart.js";

var plugin = function(chart) {
    var width = chart.chart.width;
    var height = chart.chart.height;
    var ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
    ctx.restore();
    var fontSize = (height / 114).toFixed(2);
    ctx.font = fontSize 
    ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
    var text = 80;
    var textX = Math.round((width - ctx.measureText(text).width) / 2);
    var textY = height / 2;
    ctx.fillText(text, textX, textY);
    ctx.save();
}

export default {
  extends: Doughnut,

return {     
      options: {}
}

mounted(){
    this.addPlugin({
      id: 'my-plugin',
      beforeDraw: plugin
    });
}
```